# How can I fix a table top that I spilled air freshener on?

Tags: repair, furniture

I spilled air freshener on the top my dining table. It is a veneer top with urethane finish. The area is sticky to touch. How can I fix this?

Comment: I hope you must have tried stain remover and glass cleaner.

Comment: Simply waiting a week or two *might* allow the finish to dry again. That's worked for me a time or two.

Comment: Goo Gone might be a little powerful - not sure if it would cause any damage, would want to read label but that might help.

Answer (score 1):

I did this once. I didn't notice it came off until I wiped it off.

I just sanded the whole top of the table until it was bare wood and re-stained it and added a polyurethane on top. Looks new.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, goo gone and any similar organic solvent should help... Things like mineral spirits, wd40 etc. Test those in an inconspicuous location first. Neither will harm a poly surface, but unless you finished it yourself you can never know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wiped up the "air freshener", whatever that is, already.

If the thing you spilled dissolved the finish and left it rough, then the way to fix it is to get the exact same finish liquid and rub a very small amount of it on the surface and rebuff it. You essentially need to re-build the finish using tiny amounts at a time.